# Suspending Virtual Machine hangs

Tags: virtualbox, suspend

Running Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit in a VM under Virtual Box 5.1.14 on a Windows 10 host.

For some reason suspending no longer works. The process gets hung up on a square cropped view of the sign-in screen, completely unresponsive.

When I opt to ACPI Shutdown the VM using the Virtual Box toolbar, it instead takes me back to a fully functional, un-cropped sign-in screen.

There I can log in and then shut down the machine.

Answer (score 4):

A VirtualBox guest should perfectly suspend together with the **host**. After waking up the host from suspend the guest OS will wake up too.

Because hardware power saving modes are only virtualised this may not work as expected from "suspending" a guest OS.

If we do not want to suspend the host we have several different options for a guest in VirtualBox:

#### Pause/Resume <kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

[image]

This will just pause running a virtual machine to release CPU load. While pausing a virtual machine it will be greyed out and be frozen until we resume.

From command line:

```
VBoxManage controlvm <name> pause
VBoxManage controlvm <name> resume
```

#### Save a machine's state

[image]

On closing the Virtual Box guest windows Rather instead of *power off* we can also choose to save a machine's state which would be similar to hibernating. This will terminate the instance of a virtual machine and will release all resources. On the next start the state of the machine will be fully restored from a save file on the hard disk. Depending on the hard drive read speed this is often much faster than a reboot.

From the command line:

```
VBoxManage controlvm <name>  savestate
```

Comment: Your gentle pointing out of some of the subtleties  of the host/client context that I was overlooking is greatly appreciated. 'Lock' then 'Save State' does just what I needed.